# Нестандартный цикл wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Не подскажите как выводить посты, таким образом, вот [эти](http://prnt.sc/d3gpfa) категории, а вот [эти](http://prnt.sc/d3gqa6) посты относящиеся к данной категорий, таких категорий множество будет на сайте, то есть простой цикл:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query ('cat=3');?>    
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

совершено не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Такой способ очень даже подходит, только у вас будет несколько таких выводов в цикле, в каждом из которых вы задаете ID категории, то есть один цикл это 1 класс, а посты выводимые в этом цикле соответственно будут модели